# how to send post request in angular having some fixed parameter and a variable form input

Tags: angular, rest

```
<form #postForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onCreatePost(postForm.value)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="title"
            required
            ngModel
            name="company_name"
          />
        </div>

        <button
          class="btn btn-primary"
          type="submit"
          [disabled]="!postForm.valid"
        >
          Send Post
        </button>
      </form>
```

```
onCreatePost(postData: { "secret_id":"test123", "request_id":"ce542f35-3df9-457c-a68e-0382e72364ae",
  "data":[{"id":"Test","company_name": string
  }]

   }) {

    this.http.post('http://137.135.179.164:8080/enriched_tags',postData).subscribe(response=>{
    console.log(response)

    
    })
```

REQuest

```
{"secret_id":"test123", "request_id":"ce542f35-3df9-457c-a68e-0382e72364ae",
"data":[{"id":"Test","company_name":"Microsoft"
}]
}
```

Response

```
{
   "complete_processed_data": [
       {
           "id": "Test",
           "company_name": "Microsoft”,
           "processed_data": [
               [
                   "Consumer electronics",
                   "30.69712519645691"
               ],
               [
                   "Video games",
                   "27.729570865631104"
               ],
               [
                   "games",
                   "14.379343390464783"
               ],
               [
                   "Virtual reality",
                   "14.227446913719177"
               ],
               [
                   "media and entertainment",
                   "12.015524506568909"
               ]
           ]
       }
   ],
   "success": true,
   "request_id": "ce542f35-3df9-457c-a68e-0382e72364ae"
}
```

API here is the API URL: http://137.135.179.164:8080/enriched_tags

how to send post request with fixed parameter like secret_id request_id and input variable of form i have not created model also. write code to send request with same order.

Actually i am trying to solve this problem statement

1.The user will type in a market name (text field), e.g. “Web Development”. The UI will send a POST request to a REST API - details will follow.

2.The JSON response from the REST API will contain market names and other columns as shown above. There can be any number of market names (usually the range is 0 - 10 markets). The UI has to pick these fields from the JSON response and display them in the table as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

in HTML file

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="company_name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    </ion-input>
    <ion-button type="submit" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round">
    Create
    </ion-button>
</form>
```

This is TS file just import this

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
```

This Code You write inside your Class

```
company_name: any ="";

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

submit() {

    let url = "http://137.135.179.164:8080/enriched_tags";
    let Varlue= [
        {
            id: "Test",
            company_name: "Microsoft",
        },
    ];
    let payload = {      
        "secret_id": "test123",
        "request_id": "ce542f35-3df9-457c-a68e-0382e72364ae",
        "body": Value,
    }

    let data: Observable<any> = this.http.post(url, payload);
    data.subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
  }
```

In this instead of the data you can use the Your own Variable and that you can assign here.
This will definitely help you.

Comment: but request should be in in this format {"secret_id":"test123", "request_id":"ce542f35-3df9-457c-a68e-0382e72364ae",
"data":[{"id":"Test","company_name":"Microsoft"
}]
}

Comment: Check Now I have Edited that, You can Chek that.